# Connect a field in Gravity Forms to a field in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I want to build a Gravity form where the user can search all products via an Ajax search. That search box has to be connected to the "Product title" field in WooCommerce.

So when the user types the first letter (ex.: PIN) in the Gravity form search box, the Ajax dropdown shows the 2 book titles available in the database: "PINNOCHIO" and "PINNOCHIO RETURNS", for example. Then the user selects a title that he's interested in and then submits the form.

I have no idea how to connect a field in Gravity to a field in WooCommerce. Can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add some code to dynamically populate the dropdowns. Here is the official documentation for it: https://docs.gravityforms.com/dynamically-populating-drop-down-fields

If I take their starting point and reconfigure it to work with Products, it would look like this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_51', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_51', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_51', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_51', 'populate_posts' );
function populate_posts( $form ) {

    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

        if ( $field->type != 'select' || strpos( $field->cssClass, 'populate-products' ) === false ) {
            continue;
        }

        $posts = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'numberposts' => -1,
        ) );

        $choices = array();

        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            $choices[] = array( 'text' => $post->post_title, 'value' => $post->post_title );
        }

        // update 'Select a Product' to whatever you'd like the instructive option to be
        $field->placeholder = 'Select a Product';
        $field->choices = $choices;

    }

    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution, it works perfectly. Can I also extract the 'product ID' and 'SKU' from WooCommerce and save it silently along with the form?

Comment: You can only pass one value through. My advise would be to pass the post ID rather than the post title through. Then, when using in your theme, you can simply get all needed information via the post ID.